# Number of combinations of n ordered items among r groups

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of ordered items, is there an elegant formula that states the number of unique ways that the items can be distributed among r groups, where the ordering of the items must be respected in the groups?

e.g. For the set, {a > b > c},
given one group, there is only one combination : {a, b, c}
Given two groups there are 8 combinations (if empty groups are permitted):

```
{a}, {b, c}
{a, b}, {c}
{a, c}, {b}
{b}, {a, c}
{b, c}, {a}
{c}, {a, b}
{a, b, c}, {}
{}, {a, b, c}
```

Can we easily add constraints such as minimum and maximum group sizes?

Comment: Are you considering $\{ \{a\} , \{b,c\} \} \neq \{ \{b,c \} , \{a\}\}$?

Comment: That is correct, Diego.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want $b^n$ where $b$ is the amount of boxes and $n$ the amount of elements. (Each element chooses a box, and there is no interdependence) Adding constraints is harder. [OEIS describes](http://oeis.org/A019538) what happens when you enforce “no empty boxes”.